# How do I change the font size of JFace table data

Tags: jface

I am using a Jface table viewer with OwnerDrawLabelProvider for multiline rows, how do I change the font style/size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just need to get the font you want to use and set in the event GC in the `measure` and `paint` methods.

This might be something like:

```java
private static final int TEXT_MARGIN = 3;

@Override
protected void measure(Event event, Object element)
{
  String text = ... get the text

  Font font = JFaceResources.getFont(JFaceResources.HEADER_FONT);

  event.gc.setFont(font);

  Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);

  event.width = size.x + 2 * TEXT_MARGIN;
  event.height = Math.max(event.height, size.y + 2 * TEXT_MARGIN);
}

@Override
protected void paint(Event event, Object element)
{
  String text = ... get the text

  Font font = JFaceResources.getFont(JFaceResources.HEADER_FONT);

  event.gc.setFont(font);

  event.gc.drawText(text, event.x + TEXT_MARGIN, event.y + TEXT_MARGIN, true);
}
```

Here I am using `JFaceResources.getFont` to get one of the existing JFace fonts. You can also create your own font - but be sure to do this only once  do **not** create it every time `measure` or `paint` is called.

Comment: Can you give a example of how to create own font?

Comment: Sorry but that is not something I ever do. If this is an Eclipse plugin fonts can be defined in the CSS support or the `org.eclipse.ui.themes` extension point. For a plain JFace/SWT app look at the various `Font` constructors.